# ajuda em capturar várias strings e armazena-los em uma array

Tags: java

```
String names = "<td><input type="radio" name="pergunta23g" value="SIM"/> Qual? <input type="text" name="pergunta23gQual" class="dados"> Onde<input type="text" name="pergunta23gOnde" class="dados"></td>"
```

gostaria de guardar esses três valores:
gostaria de pegar só os names sem as aspas nessa string.
como eu faço o tratamento?
armazenar em uma array de string como pergunta23g, pergunta23gQual, e pergunta23gOnde.

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta e explicar melhor? Essa string vem de onde? Há maneiras melhores de fazer uma string para depois reutilizar. Um JSON seria melhor. Se não podes mudar a estrutura da string vais precisar de regex por exemplo e aí é util se explicares o padrão que a string tem: os campos são sempre os mesmos? os nomes são sempre uma só palavra? etc

Comment: corrigi, ele segue esse padrão, mas pode variar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String names = "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"pergunta23g\" value=\"SIM\"/> Qual? <input type=\"text\" name=\"pergunta23gQual\" class=\"dados\"> Onde<input type=\"text\" name=\"pergunta23gOnde\" class=\"dados\"></td>";
String[] inputs = names.split("input");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name=\"(.*?)\"");
    
List<String> valores = new ArrayList();
for (String input : inputs) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        valores.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
    
for (String valor : valores) {
    System.out.println(valor);
}
```

Saída

> pergunta23g
>
> pergunta23gQual
>
> pergunta23gOnde

Explicações:

- Adicionei a `\` nos `"`
- Utilizei a class [Pattern](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/pattern.html)
- `name=\"(.*?)\"` vai pegar só o que tiver dentro das `"` após o `name=`
- Fiz split em um Array para utilizar o `matcher` em cada `input`
- Adicionei numa nova lista os valores corretos